# Need some ideas on how to use functional programming in JavaScript to reuse a function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Here is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kpam8g79/9/

I have a function findCommon:

```
function findCommon(ar1, ar2, ar3)
{
    // Initialize starting indexes for ar1[], ar2[] and ar3[]
    let i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    // Iterate through three arrays while all arrays have elements
    while (i < ar1.length && j < ar2.length && k < ar3.length)
    {
         // If x = y and y = z, print any of them and move ahead
         // in all arrays
         if (ar1[i] == ar2[j] && ar2[j] == ar3[k])
         {   console.log(ar1[i]+" ");   i++; j++; k++; }

         // x < y
         else if (ar1[i] < ar2[j])
             i++;

         // y < z
         else if (ar2[j] < ar3[k])
             j++;

         // We reach here when x > y and z < y, i.e., z is smallest
         else
             k++;
    }
}
```

My data set looks like this:

```
const ar1 = [1, 2, 3, 6, 8];
```

But when my dataset is an array of objects

```
const oAr1 = ar1.map(v => ({value: v, display: `value ${v}`}));
```

I still want to get the common values.

I can map oAr1 into ar1 and call the findCommon function, but that might not be performant.  I can also modify the findCommon function to take in the array of objects instead of an array of numbers, but I want to reuse findCommon.  I was wondering if I can use functional programming to somehow compose two functions so that I can reuse findCommon.

I wonder how this can be done...

Comment: Why not find the array with the smallest length and use that index for the other arrays? What exactly are you trying to do? Find what values intersect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add an optional parameter to your `findCommon` that defaults to `x => x`.

This allows you to pass a function that describes the logic required to find the value to compare.

```js
const ar1 = [1, 2, 3, 6, 8];
const ar2 = [1, 5, 6, 9];
const ar3 = [1, 4, 5, 6];

const oAr1 = ar1.map(v => ({value: v, display: `value ${v}`}));
const oAr2 = ar2.map(v => ({value: v, display: `value ${v}`}));
const oAr3 = ar3.map(v => ({value: v, display: `value ${v}`}));

findCommon(ar1, ar2, ar3);
findCommon(oAr1, oAr2, oAr3, o => o.value);

function findCommon(ar1, ar2, ar3, getValue = x => x)
{
    // Initialize starting indexes for ar1[], ar2[] and ar3[]
    let i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    // Iterate through three arrays while all arrays have elements
    while (i < ar1.length && j < ar2.length && k < ar3.length)
    {
         var x1 = getValue(ar1[i]);
         var x2 = getValue(ar2[j]);
         var x3 = getValue(ar3[k]);
         
         // If x = y and y = z, print any of them and move ahead
         // in all arrays
         if (x1 === x2 && x2 === x3)
         {   console.log(x1, ar1[i]);   i++; j++; k++; }

         // x < y
         else if (x1 < x2)
             i++;

         // y < z
         else if (x2 < x3)
             j++;

         // We reach here when x > y and z < y, i.e., z is smallest
         else
             k++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to keep findCommon exactly the same and somehow compose it with another function, but I think it's not possible for not performant.  The idea of passing in another function into findCommon is good.  This reminds me yet again functions are first class citizens in JavaScript. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to add a comparison function (like Java's `Comparator<>`) as an argument.

```
// default comparator
function defCompare(x, y) { return x > y ? 1 : x < y ? -1 : 0; }

function findCommon(ar1, ar2, ar3, cmp = defCompare)
{
    let i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    while (i < ar1.length && j < ar2.length && k < ar3.length)
    {
         // call the custom comparator
         let c1 = cmp(ar1[i], ar2[j]);
         let c2 = cmp(ar2[j], ar3[k]);

         if (c1 == 0 && c2 == 0)
         {   console.log(ar1[i] + " ");   i++; j++; k++; }

         else if (c1 == -1)
             i++;
         else if (c2 == -1)
             j++;
         else
             k++;
    }
}

// custom comparator for the objects
function customCompare(x, y) { return defCompare(x.value, y.value); }
const common2 = findCommon(oAr1, oAr2, oAr3, customCompare);
```

This works correctly ... except `console.log` prints the objects themselves. A workaround would be to change the comparator to a "value extractor" function, which returns the quantity to compare against:

```
// default: just return itself
function defValue(x) { return x; }

function findCommon(ar1, ar2, ar3, val = defValue)
{
    let i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    while (i < ar1.length && j < ar2.length && k < ar3.length)
    {
         // call the value extractor
         let v1 = val(ar1[i]);
         let v2 = val(ar2[j]);
         let v3 = val(ar3[k]);

         if (v1 == v2 && v2 == v3)
         {   console.log(v1 + " ");   i++; j++; k++; }

         else if (v1 < v2)
             i++;
         else if (v2 < v3)
             j++;
         else
             k++;
    }
}

// custom extractor for objects
function customValue(x) { return x.value; }
const common2 = findCommon(oAr1, oAr2, oAr3, customValue);
```

For your example this prints `2 8` as expected.